# Asset opening wrong unity version

Tags: unity

I'm trying to open one of my assets in unity via my browser, but when I click open in unity it opens the 2017 version, when I want to add it to my newest one.  How do i get this to work?  (I need the 2017 version, so deleting it is not an option.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about browsing the Asset Store, in which case do it within Unity, not via web browser. Go to the Window top menu, and select Asset Store.

EDIT: I was just informed in comments that the Asset Store window was removed from Unity 2020; I'm still using 2019.4 so I didn't know that.

Asset store bundles are showing up in Package Manager now, so instead of Window > Asset Store, go to Window > Package Manager. In the Package Manager window, there's a menu right above the list of packages that you can switch to My Assets.

Comment: The Asset Store does not display in the Editor in Unity 2020.1.x and newer. For these versions, you're supposed to either use your browser or the Package Manager.

Comment: doh I'm still using 2019.4 so I didn't know that. I did notice asset store bundles are showing up in Package Manager now, so I'll edit that into my answer.